# Reshape pandas dataframe which has lists as values

Tags: list, pandas, numpy, reshape

I have a pandas dataframe which has lists as values. I would like to transform this dataframe into the format in expected result. The dataframe is too large(1 million rows)

```
import pandas as pd

import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(
      [[['A', 'Second'], [], 'N/A', [6]],
      [[2, 3], [3, 4, 6], [3, 4, 5, 7], [2, 6, 3, 4]]],
      columns=list('ABCD')
      )

df.replace('N/A',np.NaN, inplace=True)

df

    A           B        C          D
0   [A,Second]  []       NaN        [6]
1   [2,3]       [3,4,6] [3,4,5,7]   [2,6,3,4]
```

## Expected result

```
0 A A
0 A Second
0 D 6
1 A 2
1 A 3
1 B 3
1 B 4
1 B 6
1 C 3
1 C 4
1 C 5
1 C 7
1 D 2
1 D 6
1 D 3
1 D 4
```

`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use double [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html):

```
df1 = df.stack()
df = pd.DataFrame(df1.values.tolist(), index=df1.index).stack()
       .reset_index(level=2,drop=True).reset_index()
df.columns = list('abc')
print (df)
    a  b       c
0   0  A       A
1   0  A  Second
2   0  D       6
3   1  A       2
4   1  A       3
5   1  B       3
6   1  B       4
7   1  B       6
8   1  C       3
9   1  C       4
10  1  C       5
11  1  C       7
12  1  D       2
13  1  D       6
14  1  D       3
15  1  D       4
```

Comment: Exactly what I wanted. Thanks! You made my day.

Answer (score 1):

```
df.stack().apply(pd.Series).stack().reset_index(2, True) \
  .rename_axis(['a', 'b']).reset_index(name='c')

    a  b       c
0   0  A       A
1   0  A  Second
2   0  D       6
3   1  A       2
4   1  A       3
5   1  B       3
6   1  B       4
7   1  B       6
8   1  C       3
9   1  C       4
10  1  C       5
11  1  C       7
12  1  D       2
13  1  D       6
14  1  D       3
15  1  D       4
```